# Moving Camera2D along with custom KinematicBody2D causes both to stop

Tags: camera, godot

I want to design a rigid body that moves up at a constant speed and can only be moved left and right manually. When I set the `Camera2D` to go vertically with the rigid body (current on), in the test mode, the rigid body moves a little and stops. (Both camera and rigid body stop).

What's wrong with this script?

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var number = 0
var player_velocity = Vector2(0,0)
var player_speed = 210

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        player_velocity.x = player_speed

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        player_velocity.x = -player_speed


    player_velocity.y = player_velocity.y + 30
    player_velocity = move_and_slide(player_velocity)
    player_velocity.x = lerp(player_velocity.x, 0, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out that there is a `RigidBody2D`, and you are using a `KinematicBody2D`. I'll assume that when you say "rigid body" you mean `KinematicBody2D`.

---

### The `Camera2D` issue

I don't know how you have setup your `Camera2D`, but I'll presume that it is a child of the `KinematicBody2D` or otherwise it is following it.

I need to point out that if the object is moving and the camera is moving with it, it will appear static on the screen. So if you don't have something else in the scene that allows you tell that it is moving, you might believe it is not.

In fact, I believe that what you describe as "moves a little and stops" is the `Camera2D` catching up to the `KinematicBody2D`. *Or was it a `RigidBody2D`? Same difference, it is catching up to whatever it is following.*